# Learning SQL from excel management reports; how best to transition?

Tags: sql, excel, vba, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am trying to learn t-sql queries, standard procedures etc and SSRS. Even some VBA. I do all my reports in Excel at the moment. I am hoping if someone can tell me how best to learn these without using the drag and drop of Excel (normal function) but instead use sql management studio and ssrs to produce the reports so I can learn t-sql. That is my objective and as my business is not giving me the opportunity to learn sql i want to use it myself to produce existing reports so i can pick up the skills? Any ideas, pls anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say you can go on Microsoft website and DL a sample database with MS SQL-SRV and practice querying yourself. Otherwise, I am not sure of how to learn (tool-wise). There is not much similarity between VBA and SQL-SRV. 
http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/

Comment: thanks Mike. Already have adv.works. I think it's more about not just theoritically learning sql querying but have sample projects to do - so you ACTUALLY learning by doing something purposeful...all i meant with VBA was translating things I may have done on Excel in a sql report (ssrs)..